# Is n-gram a special instance of bag of word? What are their differences?

Tags: nlp, representation, ngrams, bag-of-words

Is n-gram a special instance of bag of word? What are their differences? From my understanding, n-gram is when replacing the words in bag of words with n-grams, and follow the same procedures to generate the word vector.

I tried to verify the above understanding, however, I find nothing supporting this. Thus, I wonder maybe there exists some subtle difference in the procedure of calculating the word vectors that I'm not aware of?

Would appreciate answers that directly compare and contrast these two methods in word representation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An n-gram is a sequence of tokens/words **in order** (therefore bigrams to-go and go-to are different). On the other hand, a bag of words is the count of token/word occurrences in a piece of text, which losses the ordering information.

They, however, apply to different scopes. You compute a bag of words over a whole text. An ngram within a text is just a sequence of N words, where N is usually small (e.g. 2, 3). Also, note that you can have a "bag of ngrams" where you count the occurrences of ngrams instead of individual words.